# How to grab the pdf from this annoying webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I can't seem to print screen the file nor save the pdf.

I've tried to go into inspect element to find the name of the pdf so I can go to it but the web page won't let me.

the website url is : demowebsitehmlohawala.000webhostapp.com

If i can find the name of the pdf i can turn off javascript and create an iframe with the src of the pdf

Comment: http://demowebsitehmlohawala.000webhostapp.com/includes/Test%202.pdf

Comment: how did u get that?

Comment: Just posted an answer explaining :)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: The PDF is at http://demowebsitehmlohawala.000webhostapp.com/includes/Test%202.pdf.

It's a pretty neat trick to close down the tab with dev tools open!! However, we can inspect the source by pressing CTRL+U (in Firefox/Chrome) to view the source for the page. Then, we can see this ugly JS:

```
var _0x20b5=['\x73\x65\x6c\x65\x63\x74','\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6e\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6c\x64','\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6c\x65\x6d\x65\x6e\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64','\x6c\x6f\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e','\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6c\x65\x6d\x65\x6e\x74','\x62\x6f\x64\x79','\x6d\x6f\x75\x73\x65\x6c\x65\x61\x76\x65','\x76\x61\x6c\x75\x65','\x61\x62\x73\x6f\x6c\x75\x74\x65','\x6f\x6e\x63\x6c\x69\x63\x6b','\x61\x64\x64\x4c\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6e\x65\x72','\x72\x65\x61\x64\x6f\x6e\x6c\x79','\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68','\x68\x72\x65\x66','\x74\x65\x73\x74','\x69\x6e\x63\x6c\x75\x64\x65\x73\x2f\x54\x65\x73\x74\x20\x32\x20\x41\x6e\x73\x77\x65\x72\x73\x2e\x70\x64\x66\x23\x74\x6f\x6f\x6c\x62\x61\x72\x3d\x30','\x61\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6e\x74\x4c\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6e\x65\x72','\x6d\x61\x74\x63\x68\x4d\x65\x64\x69\x61','\x46\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x61\x6c\x69\x74\x79\x20\x74\x6f\x20\x72\x75\x6e\x20\x61\x66\x74\x65\x72\x20\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74\x69\x6e\x67','\x6f\x70\x65\x72\x61','\x76\x65\x6e\x64\x6f\x72','\x65\x78\x65\x63\x43\x6f\x6d\x6d\x61\x6e\x64','\x6b\x65\x79\x43\x6f\x64\x65','\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65','\x63\x6f\x70\x79','\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65\x43\x68\x69\x6c\x64','\x62\x6c\x75\x72','\x31\x30\x30\x25','\x73\x74\x79\x6c\x65','\x74\x65\x78\x74\x61\x72\x65\x61','\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74','\x6c\x6f\x67','\x73\x68\x6f\x77\x51\x75\x69\x7a','\x2d\x39\x39\x39\x39\x70\x78','\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6d\x65','\x63\x6c\x6f\x73\x65','\x6b\x65\x79\x64\x6f\x77\x6e','\x6d\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73','\x6f\x6e\x62\x65\x66\x6f\x72\x65\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74','\x73\x72\x63','\x69\x6e\x63\x6c\x75\x64\x65\x73\x2f\x54\x65\x73\x74\x20\x32\x2e\x70\x64\x66\x23\x74\x6f\x6f\x6c\x62\x61\x72\x3d\x30','\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74','\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65','\x73\x68\x6f\x77\x41\x6e\x73\x77\x65\x72'];(function(_0x22fa06,_0x333b94){var _0x22b7f6=function(_0x54b6e3){while(--_0x54b6e3){_0x22fa06['\x70\x75\x73\x68'](_0x22fa06['\x73\x68\x69\x66\x74']());}};_0x22b7f6(++_0x333b94);}(_0x20b5,-0x2d8*0x7+-0x1*0xc46+0x20f9));var _0x4bdd=function(_0x22fa06,_0x333b94){_0x22fa06=_0x22fa06-(-0x2d8*0x7+-0x1*0xc46+0x202e);var _0x22b7f6=_0x20b5[_0x22fa06];return _0x22b7f6;};var _0xd21e07=_0x4bdd;function detectmobile(){var _0xa50f98=_0x4bdd,_0x48f6d3=navigator['\x75\x73\x65\x72\x41\x67\x65\x6e\x74']||navigator[_0xa50f98('\x30\x78\x32\x35')]||window[_0xa50f98('\x30\x78\x32\x34')];return/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i[_0xa50f98('\x30\x78\x31\x66')](_0x48f6d3)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i[_0xa50f98('\x30\x78\x31\x66')](_0x48f6d3['\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72'](-0x21d3+0x2206+-0x33,0x2e7+-0xa*0x110+-0x7*-0x11b))?!![]:![];}detectmobile()&&(window[_0xd21e07('\x30\x78\x31\x34')][_0xd21e07('\x30\x78\x31\x65')]=window[_0xd21e07('\x30\x78\x38')]());(function(){var _0x4686a=_0xd21e07,_0x33c382=function(){},_0x100e8c=function(){var _0x5bba04=_0x4bdd;console[_0x5bba04('\x30\x78\x34')](_0x5bba04('\x30\x78\x32\x33'));};if(window[_0x4686a('\x30\x78\x32\x32')]){var _0x54b07c=window[_0x4686a('\x30\x78\x32\x32')](_0x4686a('\x30\x78\x65'));_0x54b07c[_0x4686a('\x30\x78\x31\x62')](function(_0x6e97c6){var _0x5c732d=_0x4686a;_0x6e97c6[_0x5c732d('\x30\x78\x61')]?_0x33c382():_0x100e8c();});}window[_0x4686a('\x30\x78\x62')]=_0x33c382,window['\x6f\x6e\x61\x66\x74\x65\x72\x70\x72\x69\x6e\x74']=_0x100e8c;}(),window[_0xd21e07('\x30\x78\x32\x31')]('\x6b\x65\x79\x75\x70',function(_0x32cb9b){_0x32cb9b['\x6b\x65\x79\x43\x6f\x64\x65']==-0x982+0x1*-0x26d2+-0xc20*-0x4&&copyStringToClipboard();}));function copyStringToClipboard(){var _0x24e7e2=_0xd21e07,_0x2c3a2e=document[_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x31\x33')](_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x31\x30'))['\x69\x6e\x6e\x65\x72\x54\x65\x78\x74'],_0x5656ea=document[_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x31\x35')](_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x32'));_0x5656ea[_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x31\x38')]=_0x2c3a2e,_0x5656ea[_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x32\x38')](_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x31\x63'),''),_0x5656ea[_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x31')]={'\x70\x6f\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6f\x6e':_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x31\x39'),'\x6c\x65\x66\x74':_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x36')},document[_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x31\x36')]['\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6e\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6c\x64'](_0x5656ea),_0x5656ea[_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x31\x31')](),document[_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x32\x36')](_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x32\x39')),document[_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x31\x36')][_0x24e7e2('\x30\x78\x32\x61')](_0x5656ea);}var imgleft,quiz1left,showQuizButton=document[_0xd21e07('\x30\x78\x31\x33')](_0xd21e07('\x30\x78\x35'));showQuizButton[_0xd21e07('\x30\x78\x31\x61')]=function(){var _0xcd40fb=_0xd21e07;showQuizButton[_0xcd40fb('\x30\x78\x66')](),imgleft=document[_0xcd40fb('\x30\x78\x31\x35')](_0xcd40fb('\x30\x78\x37')),quiz1left=_0xcd40fb('\x30\x78\x64'),imgleft['\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65'](_0xcd40fb('\x30\x78\x31\x64'),'\x31\x30\x30\x25'),imgleft['\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65']('\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74',_0xcd40fb('\x30\x78\x30')),imgleft[_0xcd40fb('\x30\x78\x63')]=quiz1left;var _0x19ef6f=document[_0xcd40fb('\x30\x78\x31\x33')]('\x71\x75\x69\x7a\x31\x6c\x65\x66\x74');_0x19ef6f[_0xcd40fb('\x30\x78\x31\x32')](imgleft);};var showAnswerButton=document[_0xd21e07('\x30\x78\x31\x33')]('\x73\x68\x6f\x77\x41\x6e\x73\x77\x65\x72');showAnswerButton[_0xd21e07('\x30\x78\x31\x61')]=function(){var _0x5d67d6=_0xd21e07;showAnswerButton['\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65']();var _0x36df09=_0x5d67d6('\x30\x78\x32\x30');imgleft['\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65']('\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68',_0x5d67d6('\x30\x78\x30')),imgleft['\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65'](_0x5d67d6('\x30\x78\x33'),_0x5d67d6('\x30\x78\x30')),imgleft[_0x5d67d6('\x30\x78\x63')]=_0x36df09;var _0x4e7965=document[_0x5d67d6('\x30\x78\x31\x33')]('\x71\x75\x69\x7a\x31\x6c\x65\x66\x74');_0x4e7965['\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6e\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6c\x64'](imgleft);},window['\x61\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6e\x74\x4c\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6e\x65\x72'](_0xd21e07('\x30\x78\x39'),function(_0x53323a){var _0x37ba64=_0xd21e07;_0x53323a[_0x37ba64('\x30\x78\x32\x37')]==-0x157c+0x23d9+-0xe4d&&(imgleft['\x72\x65\x6d\x6f\x76\x65'](),window[_0x37ba64('\x30\x78\x31\x34')][_0x37ba64('\x30\x78\x31\x65')]=window[_0x37ba64('\x30\x78\x38')]());}),$(document)[_0xd21e07('\x30\x78\x32\x62')](function(){var _0x37f2cd=_0xd21e07;imgleft[_0x37f2cd('\x30\x78\x66')](),window[_0x37f2cd('\x30\x78\x31\x34')]['\x68\x72\x65\x66']=window[_0x37f2cd('\x30\x78\x38')]();}),$(document)[_0xd21e07('\x30\x78\x31\x37')](function(){var _0x3e3518=_0xd21e07;imgleft[_0x3e3518('\x30\x78\x66')](),window['\x6c\x6f\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e']['\x68\x72\x65\x66']=window[_0x3e3518('\x30\x78\x38')]();});
```

However, by using this site (https://lelinhtinh.github.io/de4js/) we can de-obfuscate the JS. I'll skip the irrelevant parts of the code; the relevant JS give us:

```js
showQuizButton.onclick = function () {
    showQuizButton.remove(), imgleft = document.createElement('iframe'), quiz1left = 'includes/Test 2.pdf#toolbar=0', imgleft.setAttribute('width', '100%'), imgleft.setAttribute('height', '100%'), imgleft.src = quiz1left;
    var _0x19ef6f = document.getElementById('quiz1left');
    _0x19ef6f.appendChild(imgleft);
};
```

To make the code more readable:

```js
showQuizButton.onclick = function () {
    showQuizButton.remove(); 
    imgleft = document.createElement('iframe');
    imgleft.setAttribute('width', '100%');
    imgleft.setAttribute('height', '100%');
    imgleft.src = quiz1left;
    quiz1left = 'includes/Test 2.pdf#toolbar=0'; 

    let quizLeft = document.getElementById('quiz1left');
    quizLeft.appendChild(imgleft);
};
```

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

Just checking. Is the pdf file not listed, or is their an attempt to prevent it? If it is prevented, go to the menu and choose Developer Tools. You could also go to the url view-source:url.with.http.prefix and look through the code. Also, try running [this bookmarklet](http://javascript:%20void(document.oncontextmenu%20=%20null)) `javascript: void(document.oncontextmenu = null)` on the page and trying again.

Comment: Copy and paste the URL. It won't work otherwise. Try using right-click.